# Can pseudo "lock" objects be used in the Amazon S3 API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, consistency

I'm thinking about using "lock" S3 objects in order to prevent simultaneous identical operations on a given S3 object. But I have great doubts about the validity of this technical solution.

More precisely, at the beginning of an operation on an object, a lock file corresponding to the name of the object and the type of operation being done would be created.

Example: at the beginning of myOperation on myObject, lck/myObject/myOperation object would be looked for and created if it does not exist.

This "lock" object would be destroyed at the end of the operation, whether it is successful or not.

I know the standard solution would be to use a database, but the application currently does not have one. Thus, if I could handle consistency with S3 only, this would be sufficient.

My concern is that this lock object system will run in a multi-threaded / and possibly multi-nodes architecture. Now, I've read that Amazon S3 support "read after write consistency".

Does it mean that if my application 1 (node 1) / thread 2 puts a lock object on a given bucket through the Java Amazon S3 API, this lock object will be instantaneously visible to other threads and other applications using the same API?

Comment: Good answer, below, from @stdunbar.  For locking the **name** of an S3 object key (or the name of anything, really... basically a named semaphore), consider the possibility of using [consistent conditional writes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate) to a DynamoDB table created for the purpose of lock management.

Answer (score 8):

If you come here in 2023 and still think it's a good idea to use S3 for locks, this *is* possible in a guaranteed race-condition free way thanks to the strengthened consistency model, and without any forced waiting periods during lock acquisition.

1. Determine basename for the lock (e.g., `some-dir/interesting-object.lock`)
2. Writer creates empty object `some-dir/interesting-object.lock.<uuid>` in bucket. The `<uuid>` can either be generated for each lock, or once for each writer (we assume a writer doesn't write concurrently), it doesn't matter.
3. List objects with prefix `some-dir/interesting-object.lock.`
4. Check if file with "our" UUID is the oldest per `ModifiedTime`. In the extremely unlikely scenario that two `ModifiedTime`s are equal, break ties based on lexicographical ordering of UUIDs.
5. If aforementioned check succeeds, you have acquired the lock. You can now do the work. Otherwise, someone beat you to it.
6. Remove lock file (note: this means that if the acquisition failed, you should remove the lock file immediately).

This works because it's guaranteed that once a put succeeds, it will immediately show up in list calls, and each worker does list after put. If another writer even writes the object one nanosecond after us, they are still 100% guaranteed to see in their list call that our object was there first.

In order to allow removing stale/expired locks (those should be excluded in the check in step 4, and the files be deleted), this requires placing an upper bound on the duration of the critical section, although it's possible to arbitrary extend the lock time by creating new lock files with different UUIDs (some limits apply on when you can remove the old ones, but I'm too lazy to think this through right now). Also, for determining whether a lock is stale/expired, do not rely on the local machine's time, instead, use the `ModifiedTime` of the newly created lock object as a calibrated clock source.

I'm not saying it's a good idea to use lockfiles in S3, but that doesn't change the fact that it is possible.

Comment: thank you, your suggestion validates my idea. Of course, this solution requires each client to be a good citizen and respect the rules.

Comment: If `ModifiedTime` represents the initial upload time of the lock object and s3 were experiencing significant delays that resulted in the second client's PUT to have a later timestamp but return a successful response and show up in the subsequent LIST response used in step 4 _before_ the object from the first client, it is possible that both clients could think they have the lock. Unless S3 makes certain guarantees about the ordering of `ModifiedTime` between separate objects I don't see any way to avoid this problem with this method.

Comment: I haven’t tested this, but I would strongly assume that the modified time is not the initial upload time. Strong consistency means guaranteed results based on happens-before constraints, I would be surprised if S3 claims strong consistency but has no record of a key to establish the total happens-before ordering.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately it won't.  From the S3 [consistency model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel):

> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys
>   within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object
>   might not appear in the list.

and:

> Amazon S3 does not currently support object locking. If two PUT
>   requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the
>   latest time stamp wins. If this is an issue, you will need to build an
>   object-locking mechanism into your application.

So if both of your threads or processes try to create the lock in S3 they will be allowed to but last write wins so you haven't really locked anything.  Something else needs to happen for your locking to work

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I would recommend a database, but you mention that is not an option in this case.

As an alternative, you can use something like [lockable](https://lockable.dev). They provide advisory locks which can be used to control e.g. resource access like in your case.

The solution would have to use their HTTPS endpoints (as far as I can't tell they only have a Python client):

```
1. Acquire lock by making a request to https://lockable.dev/api/acquire/my-lock-name
2. Work on your object (read, edit, write)
3. Release the lock by making a request to https://lockable.dev/api/release/my-lock-name
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit me too, and it wasn't feasible to use a database at that time, so we came up with https://github.com/jfstephe/aws-s3-lock. This is a javascript implementation, but perhaps could inspire a java version if needed.