# How to lock a single S3 object temporarily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a single S3 object (file) and multiple Lambdas that have read/write access to it. Most operations are read only, but when writing to the file what I would like to do is something like this:

1. Lock myfile.json
2. `GetObject("myfile.json")`
3. Edit file contents
4. `PutObject("myfile.json")`
5. Unlock myfile.json

The goal is to ensure that a competing Lambda cannot also call `PutObject()` while it is being updated.

Is this possible with S3?

Comment: This is not something that Amazon S3 is designed to handle. If you need such fine-grained control, it might be better to use a database. Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? There might be a way to achieve your end-goal without having contention over a single object. For example, each process might be able to have its own file, but that depends on what you are actually wanting to achieve.

Comment: Last writer wins but they won't cause the resulting object to be corrupt (or some combination of the two files - it will always be one or the other). If you want a locking service, then consider [options](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamodb+locking+client) to use DynamoDB.

Comment: Terraform uses DynamoDB to manage locks for statefiles stored in S3. However, there are cases where the lockfile isn't properly removed, and you have to manually remove the lock. You could probably work-around that with an item TTL that's longer than the Lambda timeout, but beware that you could end up with a hot mess.

Answer (score 1):

S3 unfortunately does not offer a native way to handle these situations - it's more of a "blob storage" service, rather than a database. That being said, you have 2 options:

## Use a database

You can use e.g. advisory locks, like what Postgres [offers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS). There are a few things to keep in mind when doing that.

1. Make sure all your processes can access the database
2. Make sure you keep the session open while you are holding the lock.
3. There are some gotchas when it comes to working with many processes at the same time. Postgres, for example, has a hard limit for the number of concurrent sessions it allows. If you're working with e.g. a large computational grid, you may want to connect to your PG instance via [PGBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/).

## Use an external service

I've seen people use [lockable](https://lockable.dev) for things like this.

They have a [Python client](https://docs.lockable.dev/en/latest/python-client/), if you're using Python:

```
$ pip install lockable-dev
```

```
from lockable import Lock

with Lock('my-lock-name'):
   obj = get_object("myfile.json)
   obj = edit_object(obj)
   put_object(obj, "myfile.json")
```

Alternatively, you can hit their [HTTP endpoints](https://docs.lockable.dev/en/latest/https-endpoints/) directly, for example (using Python, but it's language agnostic):

```
import requests

has_lock = False

# acquire the lock
while not has_lock:
    res = requests.get('https://lockable.dev/api/acquire/my-lock-name')
    has_lock = res.json(['response'])

# do the work
obj = get_object("myfile.json)
obj = edit_object(obj)
put_object(obj, "myfile.json")

# release the lock
requests.get('https://lockable.dev/api/release/my-lock-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript then you may want to check out https://github.com/jfstephe/aws-s3-lock. Which has a S3 only, no-database solution.

A similar question was added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222819/amazon-s3-api-can-pseudo-lock-objects-be-used/73307585#73307585)

FYI I'm the author.